# Why bits are numbered from right to left?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, cpu-architecture, bit

Why are bits are numbered from right to left, in computer organization, computer architecture.

Comment: read about Little Endian versus Big Endian. wikipedia will answer it better than anyone can here in a couple paragraphs

Comment: Bits aren't really intrinsically numbered, nor do they naturally go from one "side" to the other. That said, a common convention is to write the bits of an integer with the least significant bit on the right (which matches how we usually write numbers), and that bit is numbered the zeroth bit (which numbers them by the weights the bits represent). There's no rule saying it has to be that way though, and different orders/numbering schemes are also used.

Comment: @arserbin3 they probably tried Wikipedia already, it's thorough but also overwhelming when you want a simple answer. In the context of data types represented by more than one byte, the endianess you mentioned regards the order of the sequence of bytes, not the order of bits in each individual byte, which seems to be the question. In the context of a single byte written in text, we usually write them with the same "endianness" as decimal numbers: 251 (two-hundred and fifty one) is written with its biggest digits first (2, 5, 1), like its binary form: 11111011 (256+128+64+32+16+8+0+2+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bits are not numbered from right to left. They are numbered from lowest weight (the lowest weight bit getting the number 0 or 1 depending on the convention chosen) to highest weight (which can be 15 or 16, 31 or 32, 63 or 64, ...).

One reason to number them this way is so that the number of the bit number n that counts for 2<sup>n</sup> (in start-at-0 convention) will always be the same. If they were numbered in the other direction, the weight of bit n could not be inferred from n alone, it would also depend on the width of the word being discussed.

Another reason is that it is pretty intuitive to have bits with a lower number have less weight.

They end up being numbered from right to left when written because they are written from the highest weight on the left to the lowest weight on the right. Numbers have been written so for centuries. If this is what you are wondering about, the reasons have probably been lost but [the Wikipedia page on the Hindu–Arabic numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numeral_system) may hold clues.

Comment: IBM's documentation (at least for the Power ISA) uses big endian bit numbering. In my opinion, this *is* confusing since (as you noted) the least significant bit is 63 even for 32-bit registers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, why are decimal number numbered right to left?  It's just how our system developed.  It could have gone the other way just as easy...

Answer (score 0):

It is just like any other number: lower values to the right. It just changes the base.

Answer (score 0):

Some processors number the bits from msb bit first down to lsbit, some number from lsbit to msbit, nothing to do with endianness, just how those companies decided to do it.  It is an arbitrary decision it doesnt matter in the grand scheme of things so long as everyone using that product sticks to one convention.  In some cases the bit setting and shifting instructions operate based on the chip designers convention, if not everyone uses that convention you have issues.  It also gets pretty ugly for example when using an fpga with a powerpc core which numbers from msbit of 0, but if you use verilog the natural convention is lsbit first so you have to not mess up the busses and/or create a boundary around the processor core where you swizzle everything so that it wires up directly to common peripherals, etc that are numbered the other way.

The short answer is "because that is what the designer chose", it is arbitrary.